# GridLayoutManager setSpanCount not working in OnClickListener of a button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Well, I want to change the span count of recycler view Grid layout manager's dynamically on click of a button.

```
    GridLayoutManager manager;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(manager.getSpanCount() > 16)
        {
            manager.setSpanCount(1);
        }
        manager.setSpanCount( manager.getSpanCount()+1);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }
```

but when i try to change it on OnCreate in activity

it changes the gridSpanCount in the recyclerView.

Please tell me how to fix it. and it is also not working in onTouchListener on the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting new span count value.

Comment: I tried it yesterday it wasn't working. But now it is. So anyways thanks.

Comment: This one is good for general understanding of how animations in RecyclerView work: http://www.birbit.com/recyclerview-animations-part-1-how-animations-work/

Comment: And here is an open source project with different animations: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Answer (score -1):

Here I am pasting my code snippet, not exactly what you want but may be you will get any clue.

```
 mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), MAX_COLUMNS);



        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if (position == MAX_COLUMNS) {
                    return (firstDayofWeek - 1);
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }


            }
        });

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: setSpanSizeLookup() method this for setting custom gridSpancount value for multiple rows but i want to change the spanCount of GridLayoutManager ,what you have passed in constructor as MAX_COLUMNS' in my onclickListener by the method manager.setSpanCount();